# Unwrapping Numpy "object" dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Could someone please suggest a pythonic way to unwrap a numpy array with dtype=object?

For example, if I started with:

```
array([array([ 1, 2, 3]),
       array([ 4, 5, 6]),
       array([ 7])], dtype=object)
```

I would like to return:

```
array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

as quickly as possible.  The order is important, and the actual numbers aren't just ascending integers.

The backstory is that the arrays are being pulled from a several-GB ASCII file of varying length and structure, and the data tables have a variable number of columns on each line and I just need to preserve the row-then-column order of the floats as they appear.

I'm also amenable to doing this with numpy.loadtxt if the functionality exists; I need to scan the file line-by-line and look for certain headers, then import an unknown number of columns and lines of data, and do this several times throughout the file.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input array, you can use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to *unwrap* it, like so -

```
np.concatenate(A)
```

Sample run -

```
In [325]: A
Out[325]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7])], dtype=object)

In [326]: np.concatenate(A)
Out[326]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```